# How to take control back to first column in excel sheet?

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I have a while condition which is 
Row r;

```
while(row.hasnext())
{
    r = row.next();
}
```

I want after the end of execution the control should go back to the first cell.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Selenium.

Comment: can you please help me with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "reset" your row iterator, but you can just get a new one:

```
Iterator<Row> row = sheet.rowIterator();
```

Or did I get the question wrong? Then please clarify what type "row" is.